# What does fwd mean in the heroku logs?

Tags: heroku, logging, papertrail-app

Inside the heroku logs, I have the following line...

```
Aug 06 21:50:18 coolApp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/about.jpg" host=coolapp.com fwd="78.7.88.177,643.198.55.55" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=43ms status=500 bytes=420
```

My question is what does `fwd` represent? I see they are IP addresses. Are they IP addresses from the user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-router-log-format):

`fwd`: HTTP request `X-Forwarded-For` header value

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For):

The `X-Forwarded-For` (XFF) HTTP header field is a common method for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer.

So I think you are right when the http requests are from a user's browser.

Comment: while the docs don't specify it, this is the header value that is SENT to the downstream application, not the header value that is received by Heroku. this means that the header also includes the IP address of the client that connected to Heroku.

if you want to dive in real deep on this topic, I recommend: https://adam-p.ca/blog/2022/03/x-forwarded-for/